# listview in fragment always returns the same height

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I tried to get the height value of a listview used in a fragment by using this code:

```
listView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new   ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // make sure it is not called anymore 
        listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        listView.getHeight();//return zero
    }
});
```

However it always return zero.

Then, I tried another solution that other people suggested.

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      listView.getHeight();//return zero
    }
  }
)
```

It also returns zero.

Then, I put listView.getHeight() inside listView.onItemClickListener() to make sure the listView is fully drawn. To my surprise, it always returns the same value (not zero) regardless of the number of items inside this ListView.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

the fragment inflates listView.xml

listView.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:divider="@color/divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml for the parent of listview

Comment: "it always returns the same value (not zero) regardless of the number of items inside this ListView" - The ListView's height does not depend on the number of list items it contains. What are you trying to determine exactly?

Comment: I am trying to get the height of a listView used in a fragment. Why the listview's height does not depend on the number of items? Can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: The height of the ListView is the height of the widget the user sees, i.e. the size of the View on screen. If you're trying to get the total height that all of the list items would occupy if shown at once, this won't do it.